Kalman Filter: Sequential Updates vs Simultaneous updates
There is this very thoughtful answer. It proves that if the observation noise is independent, then sequential update is the same as simultaneous update.
Kalman filtering: Processing all measurements together vs processing them sequentially
However in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Information_filter setup, it says explicitly that we can sequentially add all the updates one after another, and didn't mention independence condition. The derivation also makes sense to me.  Given Kalman Filter and Information Filter are equivalent, I am not sure why that's the case?

The wikipedia page is only correct if the $N$ measurements are independent. The information filter does work the same as the kalman filter.

Can you elaborate why? The information filter page on wikipedia doesn't seem to assume that
